# Iterating a loop with a pause

Tags: python

I am working to integrate with an API that has a limit on the number of requests per second. Is there a way, when running a `for` loop in python to delay each cycle? Conceptually, something like --

```
def function(request):
    for x in [a,b,c,d,...]:
        do something
        wait y seconds
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import time
...
time.sleep(5)
```

This will sleep for 5 seconds. See http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep